# C++ ABI Compatability Question w/ Tensorflow

Tags: c++, tensorflow, g++

I'm trying to custom-compile a tensorflow operation and seem to be running into trouble with C++ ABI compatability.

Here's my compile command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -shared tf_bundler.cc ceres_bundler_op.cc tf_bal_problem.cc -o ceres_bundler_op.so -fPIC -I/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include -I/usr/include/ceres -L/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow -ltensorflow_framework -lceres -lgflags  -O2 -w -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1
```

However, I get an undefined error when trying to use the resulting library in Python:

```
ipython
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jul 20 2018, 09:16:11) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.4.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for 
extra details.

In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:34: 
FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of 
issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In 
future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == 
np.dtype(float).type`.
from ._conv import register_converters as 
_register_converters

In [2]: co = tf.load_op_library("./ceres_bundler_op.so")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-68f39c050b6b> in <module>()
----> 1 co = tf.load_op_library("./ceres_bundler_op.so")

/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py in load_op_library(library_filename)
 54     RuntimeError: when unable to load the library or get the python wrappers.
 55   """
---> 56   lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
 57 
 58   op_list_str = py_tf.TF_GetOpList(lib_handle)

NotFoundError: ./ceres_bundler_op.so: undefined symbol: _Z13tf_bundle_adjiiiddPiS_Pfb
```

So the problem looks to be with tf_bundle_adj, but that's it tf_bundler.cc which was explicitly compiled with _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1

I just recompiled ceres, so that library should be with the same ABI.  Querying tensorflow with

```
    In [3]: tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()
    Out[3]: 
    ['-I/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/include',
 '-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1']
```

reveals that it is also compiled with this ABI.  Not sure where the problem is -- any ideas?

In case it's relevant, I'm using gcc 7.3.0 on a Gentoo box.

Comment: I am not sure how `tf.load_op_library` works, but my impression is that it loads you `so` library but it fails to load Ceres or other libraries. I am not sure if these should be in your `PATH`, a specific path (the current path, the library path, something else?) or TensorFlow just expects your library not to have any dependencies besides TensorFlow itself... Have you tried compiling Ceres (and maybe Gflags) statically into your library? (I don't know if this is straightforward or not)

Comment: Thanks jdehesa; that certainly seems worth trying.  I *think* that this issue is somewhat different though, because the function it's saying is undefined is in tf_bundler.cc (my code).  From the poking around I've done, it looks like a C++ ABI issue.  E.g. on the tensorflow discussion they recommend setting -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 for similar issues.  BUT my TF was compiled with that flag set to 1 as were the other libraries and in particular tf_bundler.cc

Comment: O.k., so I'm starting to think this is not an ABI version issue but just a question of getting the headers to match up.  I'd originally forgotten to pass a parameter in!  I will play with this for a bit and confirm if that is indeed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O.k., the whole thing with the ABI was a red herring.  It turned out to be an issue with namespaces.  The code I was using was modified from a function that put it in the ceres::examples namespace.  So using nm I found the following functions:

```
ceres_bundler_op.so:                 U tf_bundle_adj(int, int, int, double, double, int*, int*, float*, float*, bool)
ceres_bundler_op.so:0000000000010700 T ceres::examples::tf_bundle_adj(int, int, int, double, double, int*, int*, float*, float*, bool)
```

The first of these was the missing function that caused the problem; the second was what was actually defined in tf_bundler.cc

Fixed it by removing the definition from the scope of namespace commands.  My C++ is rusty, it having been about 20 years since I've used it!